# How to Append a column in parse.com database

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Hey guys I was looking through parse.com examples and documentation but haven't been able to figure out how to change the value of something that's stored in a column in a parse class(specifically a string that's a number e.g., Column name:ExampleColumn - string - 5) . For example I want to do something like this when a button is clicked

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject> ("ExampleClass");
    ExampleColumn = ExampleColumn + 1; /* obviously this won't work but it shows exactly what i   want to do with the column, so that this would make ExampleColumn = 6 */    
}
```

Comment: In the REST api , you just do a PUT with json value for the update value of 'exampleColumn'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Parse, you don't work directly with columns. You work with objects. So, if you want to change the value of "a column", you need to

1. fetch the object (row) you want to change
2. edit the property on that object
3. save the object again.

Comment: So what would that code look like? Sorry i'm still a little confused, I know how to save the object and have an idea of how to fetch the object (It's displayed in a dynamic listview in my app) but editing the object is where i'm stuck. Thanks again for your response!

Comment: ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ExampleClass");
        
query.whereEqualTo("ExampleColumn", myList.get(position).getExampleColumn());   // for example, how would you edit the example column here

Comment: When you have the object, you write any property to it with object.set(...). Then you save it. Just check out the Android guide for how to write to and save objects. Any property is equal to a "column" in traditional databases.

Answer (score 0):

If the column data type is string you have to convert to integer before increment it.

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery ("ExampleClass");
query.whereEqualTo("objectId",your_object_id);
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (object == null) {
      Log.d("score", "The getFirst request failed.");
    } else {
      int val=Integer.parseInt(object.getString("exampleColumn"));
      val++;
      object.put("exampleColumn",val);
      object.saveInBackground();
    }
  }
});
```